# How to get most accurate Point-Point distance queries in Europe with Spatialite

Tags: distance, spatialite, geodjango, geography-data-type

I have a GeoDjango app, currently on PostGIS, which I am converting to use Spatialite db instead.  I have no specialised knowledge about GIS systems :(

The locations table has a `Geography` column storing a single point in SRID 4326 per row, originally derived from lat/long data.

It's a long time since I built the original app but I believe I had read advice like:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/gis/model-api/#geography-type
https://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#PostGIS_GeographyVSGeometry

...and this led me to believe that I would get more accurate point-to-point distance measurements with out-of-the-box GeoDjango queries by using the `Geography` type.

I have loaded the data in Spatialite, the same table now has a `Point` column. The data was dumped and loaded via GeoDjango and the values look the same.

When I do the distance queries I get similar but different results between PostGIS and Spatialite. The discrepancy gets larger with larger distances.

If I inspect the method Django is using in PostGIS:

```
SELECT ...
  ST_Distance("locations"."geopoint", ST_GeogFromWKB(\'\\x0101000020e6100000c3bb5cc47762c0bf1893fe5e0ac14940\'::bytea))
    AS "distance"
  FROM locations
  WHERE ...
```

vs in Spatialite:

```
SELECT ...
  COALESCE(Distance("locations"."geopoint", GeomFromText(\'POINT (-0.128005 51.508129)\',4326), 0), 0)
    AS "distance"
  FROM locations
  WHERE ...
```

...this seems to fit with what I read about "Geography" vs "Geometry".

Would it be correct to say that the PostGIS Geography query is more accurate?

And reading here https://www.gaia-gis.it/spatialite-3.0.0-BETA/spatialite-cookbook/html/srid.html it sounds like the key to getting accurate distances in Geometry queries is to use an appropriate projection, would that be correct?

If so, is there a way to get more accurate distance queries in Spatialite by re-projecting my points in a different SRID?

My use case would be *"Select all rows where distance from <some point> is less than X kilometres"*.  All the points are in Europe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SpatiaLite function for distance measurement is more advanced nowadays. It's a pity that search engines do not find the up-to-date documentation about the SQL functions of SpatiaLite [www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-5.0.0.html](http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-5.0.0.html).

> ST_Distance( geom1 Geometry , geom2 Geometry , use_ellipsoid Boolean )
> : Double precision
>
> Summary: return the distance between geom1 and geom2 (measured in
> meters). If the use_ellipsoid argument is set to TRUE the precise (but
> slower) distance will be computed on the Ellipsoid, otherwise will be
> computed on the Great Circle (approximative, but faster). This
> function only supports Long/Lat coordinates, and will return NULL for
> any planar CRS

The ST_Distance function should fit extremely well for your EPSG:4326 data. Notice the third parameter "use_ellipsoid". It must appear in the SQL query or otherwise the distance function falls to use the traditional method "return the distance between geom1 and geom2 (always measured in CRS units)".

Comment: Thanks, this sounds exactly what I was looking for!  I will work out how to persuade Django to use this feature...

Comment: GeoDjango calls this option `spheroid`... using `Distance(..., spheroid=True)` I now get distances in PostGIS and Spatialite that match to within a fraction of a metre! 

Comment: Nice to know, I have not used that feature myself.